# Javascript function with two different states

Tags: javascript

How to implement func function:

```
func(); // console.log('state1');
func(); // console.log('state2');
func(); // console.log('state1');
func(); // console.log('state2');
//...
```

But without setting properties to func and variables in closures.

Comment: How to implement what? You don't have anything here. You are calling a function called `func` but you have no function called `func` I'm not sure what your question is...

Comment: @NewToJS I think the question *is* how to implement `func`.

Comment: Well, you could use a global variable instead, but there are good reasons that's frowned upon.

Comment: "But without setting properties to func and variables in closures." — Is there a reason for banning the standard approaches?

Comment: @DavinTryon thank you, i'm look at this and wondering why the console.log() is commented out and func() posted multiple times, maybe i'm just reading it wrong.

Comment: For those who do not understand, `func()` should `console.log` "state1" the fist time, and "state2" the second time, etc. But you do need to save the state in some kind of variable.

Comment: "state" term automatically means it's saved somewhere somehow. It would be helpful that the original task was explained, since at the moment "using global variables" is a solution, but I'm sure OP won't accept it.

Comment: Local storage?  How about calling a server with ajax to read/set a field in a database? :)  That's the worst I can think of...

Comment: @blex — That's a pretty unintuitive way of using a global

Comment: @zerkms — No, but if a global is going to be used, then it might as well be explicit rather than using the `this` variable to access it.

Comment: @Quentin is right (as he is most of the time :)

Comment: @DavinTryon: those are still globals, but really remote globals! +1

Comment: I think about 
`function func() { (function n() { console.log('state1'); func = function(){ console.log('state2'); func = n; }})()}` but this looks strange

Comment: @VladimirKovalchuk you're keeping state in a free variable (`func` is) in a closure. So your solution does not fit your own limitations.

Comment: You're right! There must be a six different solutions to this task... I found only two. Must be a solution without variables at all

Comment: @VladimirKovalchuk: nonetheless, it's a clever little trick that is occasionally useful.

Comment: @Vladimir Kovalchuk: for the task to be "real" it must have a better description. Show your two though. I don't believe there is something other than "store it in a global variable" available that is a generic JS (what I mean here is that JS that does not rely on host-specific stuff) and fits the current limitations.

Comment: @zerkms my solutions - 1 `var func = (function(){
 var f = 'state1'
 return function(){ console.log(f = (f == 'state1')?'state2':'state1') }
}) ()` 
 2  `function func() {
  console.log(func.f = (func.f == 'state1') ? 'state2' : 'state1');
}`
But also this can be done without variables.

Comment: @VladimirKovalchuk Vladimir "this can be done without variables" --- it's highly unlikely.

Comment: @zerkms we can do this with generators...

Comment: @VladimirKovalchuk generators are not in JS yet. But indeed - that's a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find a trick:

```
func = (function* (){
    while (true) { 
         console.log('state1'); yield null;    
         console.log('state2'); yield null; 
    } 
})()
func = func.next.bind(func);
func();
func();
```

Comment: It does not comply the function interface though.

Comment: @zerkms, I fixed this

Answer (score 2):

Well, using global variables hasn't been denied, so I don't see a reason for this not to be a valid answer:

```
var func = function() {
    if (typeof state == 'undefined') {
        state = false;
    }
    state = !state;
    console.log(state ? 'state1' : 'state2');
};
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/zo94u90f/

Answer (score -1):

This does not match the "no-closures" requirement.  But I don't know of any way to do that except to use global variables.  This seems quite clean though.  What's the objection to closure variables?

```
var func = (function() {
    var calls = 0;
    var states = ["state1", "state2"];
    return function() {
        var state = states[calls++ % states.length];
        console.log(state);
    };
}());
```